# How to invoke the `next()` element constantly in another function?

Tags: javascript

I am not very well familiar with **JS**. I am looking for a method of generating `NEXT ()` subsequent array elements, which will be part of the string for the next displayed images in my **Django** project.

For that sake I built a generator in my **JS** file:

```
function* indexGenerator() {
    let index = 1;
    while (index < 78) {
        yield index++;
    }
    if (index = 78)
        yield* indexGenerator();
  };
```

...and now I'm trying to figure out how to use it in another function where the goal is to implement `next().value` as a part of my string's path: `var file = "<img src=\"slides/light_" + number.next().value + ".jpg\" />";`

I tried several approaches that don't work. Among other things, this:

```
setInterval(function animationslider()
{
    var number = indexGenerator();
    var file = "<img src=\"slides/light_" + number.next().value + ".jpg\" />";
    document.getElementById("animation-slider").innerHTML = file;
}, 5000);
```

I thought that having `setInterval()` would yield the next element from my generator for each time interval. But it was a misconception.

The overall idea is to have 77 images that will be changed every 5 sec having a generator as an engine. How to fix the function `animationslider()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine, you just need to put `var number = indexGenerator();` outside your timeout:

```
var number = indexGenerator();

setInterval(function animationslider()
{
    var file = "<img src=\"slides/light_" + number.next().value + ".jpg\" />";
    document.getElementById("animation-slider").innerHTML = file;
}, 5000);
```

because having it inside the timeout callback will re-initialize the `number` variable with a fresh instance of indexGenerator.